# How can I pass copies of object to the function in the .done() of a $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, typescript

I have the following code:

```
function doDialogAjax(link: Link. modal: Modal) {
    $.ajax( link.Url,
    {
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html'
    })
        .done(onDialogDone)
        .fail(onDialogFail);
}

function onDialogDone(data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) {
    var x = data;
    // I need to access link.abc and modal.def properties here
}
```

How can I send the link object to my onDialogDone() function? I 
seem to remember there is some way to send specify context information objects but I can't find any examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the context-key to change the value of `this` inside your callback:

```
function doDialogAjax(link: Link. modal: Modal) {
    $.ajax( link.Url,
    {
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        context: {
           link: link,
           modal: modal
        }
    })
        .done(onDialogDone)
        .fail(onDialogFail);
}

function onDialogDone(data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) {
    var x = data;
    // this refers to the context-object, with keys [link, modal]
    console.log(this.link);
    console.log(this.modal)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.done(onDialogDone({link : link, modal : modal}, 'success', data))
```

Something like this?

Comment: Ok maybe I wasn't clear enough. I ment it like this: `$.ajax( link.Url,
    {
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        context: {
           link: link,
           modal: modal
        }
    })
        .done(onDialogDone({link : link, modal : modal}, 'success', data)),
        .fail(onDialogFail);`

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. Function name followed by opening parentheses  means immediate invocation.